# Quick migration to ELL

Tags: support

Why was this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/237092/why-dog-eats-dog-cannot-be-a-phrasal-adjective-but-dog-eat-dog-can)  quickly migrated to ELL? I think the question posed is just apparently an elementary  one. It may well find a proper answer on ELL, of course, but why was it out of place on ELU?

Comment: It isn't. It drives me nuts when people migrate a Q because they think it might suit different Stack better. That isn't the point. We should be fighting to retain all Qs that are on topic here.

Comment: It's asking for a reason for the presence or absence of a particular affix in a fixed-phrase idiom. "Nobody knows" is the answer.  I don't want to fight to retain it.